# Cant upload files with paperclip/S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip

Hello I am trying to create a backoffice for an already made project(the project it's fully working)

I'm having problems uploading files, when I try to create a new Training the service throws a rollback. if i leave the the photo blank it creates the training normally

controller:

```
def create
 service_params = permitted_attributes
 service_params = service_params.merge(owner_user: User.find(service_params[:owner_user]))

 service = CreateTrainingService.new(service_params)

 if service.call
   redirect_to training_path(service.training)
 else
   redirect_to trainings_path
 end
end
```

service:

```
 def create_training
@training = Training.new(
  owner_user:         @owner_user,
  owner_club_id:      @owner_club_id,
  name:               @name,
  description:        @description,
  address:            @address,
  city:               @city,
  country:            @country,
  level_id:           @level_id || Level.first.id,
  public:             @public || false,
  distance:           @distance,
  start_date:         DateTime.strptime(@start_date + ' ' + @start_time, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"),
  road_type:          @road_type,
  race:               @race,
  participants_limit: @participants_limit,
  latitude:           @latitude,
  longitude:          @longitude,
  google_place_id:    @google_place_id,
  cover_input:        @cover,
  default_cover:      @default_cover,
  open_runner_link:   @open_runner_link,
  disciplines:        @disciplines
)
end
```

this is the relevant part of the view:

```
 <div uk-form-custom>
    <%= f.file_field :cover %>
    <button class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-margin-top" type="button" tabindex="-1">Select file</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Add the console rollback error here.

Comment: I am sure may be you didn't add the keys for S3 buckets properly.

Comment: Please show the model with your paperclip attachment

Comment: this is my console error: http://imgur.com/a/zF1Wd

the model is working fine because it's already working it an API, i think i'm doing something wrong in the form / backoffice controller

Comment: Are you uploading to s3? where is the s3 client configuration and the upload api call?

Comment: solved the problem. solution is using :cover_input for input from API and a new field :cover for input from rails view form